# Partitioning a column into multiple columns in KUSTO

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Below is the table[pic attached] , I have to partition Formattedmessage column into multiple columns like containerid, operationname, corelationid and productversion etc..

[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m06xn.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m06xn.png)

Comment: We aren't going to write your code for you. Show us what's not working.

Answer (score 3):

you could use the `parse` operator for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parseoperator

if you need help with writing a full solution, please provide a sample input as text (e.g. `print myValue = 'replace with a sample input'`)